# TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD event not firing on my Galaxy Nexus ICS 4.0.2

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I'm trying to get the tilted angle of the phone, and I have this activity that works perfectly on my LG Optimus S with 2.3 on it, but on my stock Verizon Galaxy Nexus running ICS 4.0.2 the TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD event never fires.

Because the TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD event never fires, I don't get the mGravs array needed to pass into the SensorManager.getRotationMatrix. So I can't tell the phone's angle. Like I mentioned this code works great on my other device and I can see the tilt angle of the phone with no problems.

Any know why I wouldn't get this event with my Galaxy Nexus? Have there been any changes to the SDK that would prevent this from working?

Here is my activity:

```
package com.rain.united;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Gameplay extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
    private TextView mOrientationData;
    private SensorManager mSensMan; 
    private float mAzimuth; 
    private float[] mGravs = new float[3]; 
    private float[] mGeoMags = new float[3]; 
    private float[] mOrientation = new float[3]; 
    private float[] mRotationM = new float[9]; 
    private float[] mRemapedRotationM = new float[9]; 
    private boolean mFailed; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        mOrientationData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orientation_data);

        mSensMan = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE); 
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensMan.registerListener(this, mSensMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), 
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI); 
        mSensMan.registerListener(this, mSensMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), 
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI); 
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensMan.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE) 
            return; 
        Log.d("united", "anything");
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) { 
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                //I NEVER GET TO THIS CODE ON MY GALAXY NEXUS
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mGravs, 0, 3); 
                Log.d("united", mGravs.toString());
                break;  
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER: 
                // Here let's try another way: 
                for (int i=0;i<3;i++) mGeoMags[i] = event.values[i]; 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    return;
        } 
        if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationM, null, mGravs, mGeoMags)){ 
            //Rotate to the camera's line of view (Y axis along the camera's axis) 
            //TODO: Find how to use android.opengl.Matrix to rotate to an arbitrary coordinate system. 
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationM, SensorManager.AXIS_X, 
                    SensorManager.AXIS_Z, mRemapedRotationM); 
            SensorManager.getOrientation(mRemapedRotationM, mOrientation); 
            onSuccess(); 
        } else {
            onFailure();
        }
    }

    void onSuccess(){ 
        if (mFailed) mFailed = false; 
        //      Convert the azimuth to degrees in 0.5 degree resolution. 
        mAzimuth = (float) Math.round((Math.toDegrees(mOrientation[0])) *2)/ 2; 
        //      Adjust the range: 0 < range <= 360 (from: -180 < range <= 180). 
        mAzimuth = (mAzimuth+360)%360; // alternative: mAzimuth = mAzimuth>=0 ? mAzimuth : mAzimuth+360; 
        mOrientationData.setText("Azimuth= " + mAzimuth); 
    } 
    void onFailure() { 
        if (!mFailed) { 
            mFailed = true; 
            mOrientationData.setText("didn't get rotation info"); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to deal with it?

Comment: We have the same problem on Galaxy S3 and Asus tablet. Did someone fix this nasty thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE) return;
```

Remove this line.  The magnetic sensor is returning this accuracy status and your code is throwing away these events.

Comment: Thx, it helped on SE Xperia Mini X8 and Samsung Galaxy S1 (and probably many more)